# How to beautify alert msg with jquery in php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uialertview, alert

I have too many alert msgs according to my programming conditions, and i wants to beautify them coz thatz looking normal and weird.

```
if(True)
{
   echo "<script>alert('blah blah blah');</script>";
}

if(False)
{
   echo "<script>alert('blah blah blah');</script>";
}
```

I tried too many jquery plugins but they work with some specific event like onclcik, onblur, onhover, onload, onsubmit...

In above code how can i customize alert msgs without using any event

Comment: What I did to make "beautiful" alert boxes easily was create a custom class with a constructor that accepts a string. Then I just instantiate the class with the string and it looks nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for custom alerts (modal dialogs).

Try it here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message

PS: There is no `echo` in JavaScript.

[image]

> Nice modal dialog!

## Codez:

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That is a pretty sexy box. I was just curious about the answers, but I think I'm gonna use this myself x_x. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery UI dialog.

It can be opened directly just like an alert. just write you message to some element like a div, and how it on ready.

See [jQuery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Sample code:

js:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>
```

html:

```
<div id="dialog" title="My Alert">
    <p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Avoid modal messages if possible. They can be quite irritating, cause your whole screen is locked. Same goes for alerts.

Answer (score 1):

The box that popups when calling alert function, can not be customized through css. It's a browser component so takes the style from the browser and not from the page. So you have to use a popup dialog like [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this plugin to beautify alert: http://plugins.jquery.com/alert-beautifier/